# "Could not find or load main class de.fhg.fokus.hss.main.HSSContainer"- OpenIMSCore's FHoSS

Tags: voip, ims

Error when trying to build the OpenIMS FHoSS HSS, following http://openimscore.sourceforge.net/docs/FHoSS/using.html and running the `startup.sh` script.

```
~/openimscore-hss/FHoSS$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 ./scripts/startup.sh
Building Classpath
Classpath is lib/xml-apis.jar:lib/xercesImpl.jar:lib/xerces-2.4.0.jar:lib/xalan-2.4.0.jar:lib/struts.jar:lib/servlet-api.jar:lib/mysql-connector-java-3.1.12-bin.jar:lib/mx4j-3.0.1.jar:lib/log4j.jar:lib/junit.jar:lib/junitee.jar:lib/jta.jar:lib/jsp-api.jar:lib/jdp.jar:lib/hibernate3.jar:lib/ehcache-1.1.jar:lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:lib/commons-validator.jar:lib/commons-logging.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:lib/commons-lang.jar:lib/commons-fileupload.jar:lib/commons-digester.jar:lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar:lib/commons-beanutils.jar:lib/cglib-2.1.3.jar:lib/catalina-optional.jar:lib/catalina.jar:lib/c3p0-0.9.1.jar:lib/base64.jar:lib/asm.jar:lib/asm-attrs.jar:lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar::log4j.properties:..
Error: Could not find or load main class de.fhg.fokus.hss.main.HSSContainer
```

Answer (score 0):

The script should be run from the `deploy/` directory.

```
~/openimscore-hss/FHoSS/deploy$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 ./startup.sh
```